# Three.js pick object after remove

Tags: javascript, three.js

Picking and objects code is one of the most popular:

```
function Picking(event) {
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
event.preventDefault();
mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {

    }
} else {
     INTERSECTED = null;
}
}
```

The description: in scene are two objects - cube and sphere. Sphere is first to camera and cube is second. The Sphere has ID1 and cube ID2. Picking is working.

The problem: after deleting the sphere (scene.remove(sphere)); Picking is giving the ID1, so, it seems like sphere is invisible. What is the problam?
The picture of the example: [Picture](https://s32.postimg.org/bju7l9r9h/image.png)

This code is not giving the result:

```
for (i = sphere.children.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
       object = sphere.children[i];
       object.geometry.remove;
       object.material.remove;
       object.geometry.dispose();
       object.material.dispose();
       scene.remove(object);
       sphere.remove(object);
   }
```

or

```
recur(sphere);
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].geometry.remove;
        objects[i].material.remove;
        objects[i].geometry.dispose();
        objects[i].material.dispose();
        scene.remove(objects[i]);
        sphere.remove(objects[i]);
    }

function recur(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
    objects.push(obj);
  }

  for (var i in obj.children) {
    recur(obj.children[i]);
  }
}
```

The code that add objects:

```
var ObjLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
var ii;
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var oldModel = scene.getObjectByName('group');
if (oldModel !== undefined) { scene.remove(oldModel); }

      ObjLoader.load("path/model.json", addModelToScene);
      group.name = "group";
      scene.add(group);


function addModelToScene(model) {
     recur(model);
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].castShadow = true;
        objects[i].receiveShadow = true;
    }
    model.name = "ModelName";
    group.add(model)
 }
```

So, The .json model consists of some objects (1..n);
This .json model is added into group.
With picking the side of the cube (may be material) is selectable, but not removable. but the position can be changed.

Thank you.

Comment: have you updated the renderer after removing the object from the scene? so running `renderer.render(scene, camera);`

Comment: thank you for reply, sure, renderer is in update part...

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle sample?

Comment: sorry please, but I don't know how to work with this service... All the code is CopyPast from the project. The cube and the sphere are .obj and .js files with ObjLoader. The Process is: loading model (cube), put him in group ( var group = new THREE.Object3D(); ), load second one and put him in same group ...... that is all...

Answer (score 0):

Change your picking logic a little, store all your objects into array when creating them:

```
 /*var objects = [];
  var  group = new THREE.Object3D();
 create your mesh add to array*/
 objects.push(MyMesh);
 /*now we have a reference all the time in objects[0] , objects[1]*/
 objects[0].displose();   check syntax been a while*/

customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
{
    uniforms: customUniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    //wireframe: true,
    side: THREE.FrontSide 

}   );


function ground (){

var map = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024,1024, 128, 128);//Use planebufferGeo

map.dynamic = true;

_terrain = new THREE.Mesh(  map, customMaterial );

_terrain.material.needsUpdate = true;

_terrain.geometry.dynamic = true;

_terrain.geometry.vertexColors = true; 

_terrain.material.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

_terrain.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;

_terrain.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

objects.push(_terrain);

scene.add(_terrain );
}
```

So I used this in a situation where it was a picking game type, I used an array to store the mesh and i could manipulate the vertices / faces etc edit the array to make changes.
It was an easier way to compare things and check data.

```
function animate() {

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    var faceIndex = intersects[0].faceIndex;
    var obj = intersects[0].object;
    var geom = obj.geometry;
     //etc
```

Comment: big thanks to your reply! I will try your method and write the results soon! Again thank you )

Comment: unfortunetly Three.js is giving error: "object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. Array [  ]". And group[0] is undefined...

Comment: yes, I have tried like you said - but it's not the solution for problem. I realised that I can't delete objects at all. just all group can be deleted. For example, I have picked one side of the cube, I can change the position of this side, or of the group. But I can't delete this side. And, if i will delete the group - all sides of cube will disappear, but still will be picked. I'v added the "adding code" in the question. Pleace, may be that will help.

Comment: You can dig further in an array... myarray[0][1]..  console.log(myarray[1][0]. check if there in there or check the console.log(scene[0]) and find it

Comment: yep. i think i will make the array in the end, if it is better than empty object. But... i think I found the weak point of this issue... The model. She is composite. And now I checked and found that all objects in it has ID's, and I can't remove any of objects. Even if I'm doing loading in empty scene and just an .json file. Without any groups, arrays, etc... Why I can't remove object?... if I know ID. or Name. and Picking is picking him...